# How can I play a playlist using Spotify API in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify, libspotify, spotipy

I have been trying to play a spotify playlist using spotipy using the authorization code flow and I keep getting that error :

```
HTTP Error for PUT to https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play returned 403 due to Player command failed: Premium required
```

I checked and I am a prenium user. I managed to have access to the playlist as I can print them, but I can not modify or play one of the playlist.

Comment: First question: indeed you get "Premium required" because you need the authorization code flow

Comment: Second question: `I can not modify or play one of the playlist.` you need to tell us more about that. Please update your question to only reflect your second problem, because it seems you've already solved the first one

Comment: Mybad, I didn't explain correctly. There are two ways to connect to a user account using the Authorization Code Flow and using the Client Credentials Flow. I've used both method but it only allowed me to get metadata. Whenever I try to create or modify a playlist or use the playback I get that error saying I need prenium privilege, even though I am already prenium. I don't know if it is because it is a family prenium account instead of a regular one ?

Comment: ok, in my experience this message is usually correct: either this is not the correct account (double check with `sp.me()`) or the Authorization Code Flow isn't working properly and the token you use doesn't belong to any user. Can you please share a minimal working example (auth included)?

Comment: `import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import json

client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=my_client_id,client_secret=my_secret_id)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

playlists = sp.user_playlists('spotify')

sp.me()` and I got this error this time `HTTP Error for GET to https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/ returned 401 due to Unauthorized.`

Comment: You are not using the authorization code flow but the client credentials flow. For user endpoints, don't use `SpotifyClientCredentials`, use `SpotifyOAuth`. Have another look at the example given in the README https://github.com/plamere/spotipy#with-user-authentication